# how to add unicode characters in vscode latex (input)

Tags: unicode-math, auto-completion, vscode

In vscode, I would like to type something like \scrK  to get .  There is a Unicode Latex plugin but it takes several extra keystrokes.  What would be the easiest way to accomplish this?

Thanks!

(I'm using the LaTeX workshop plugin)

Comment: So you want to define a command `\scrK` that outputs a Unicode char? Or do you want to define a keystroke, that put a Unicode character into your tex file? Should it be exactly the Unicode char (0x1D4A6) or would something like `\mathcal{K}` or `\mathscr{K}` (with `\usepackage{mathrsfs}`) be possible? Should it run with LaTeX or would XeLaTeX also be an option?

Comment: Yes, just `\scrK` to output a Unicode character (and likewise for other characters).  I use `lualatex` with `unicode-math`.  Sorry that wasn't clear.

Comment: And exactly the Unicode character

Comment: doesn't `\mscrK`  or `\symcal{K}` give that already?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer That seems to be the correct answer. The char can also be found in [`unicode-math`](https://ctan.org/pkg/unicode-math): [List of symbols defined by the package](https://ftp.fau.de/ctan/macros/unicodetex/latex/unicode-math/unimath-symbols.pdf) by searching for "1D4A6" (hex code of the char).

Comment: So this might also be a duplicate of the famous question [How to look up a symbol or identify a letter from a math alphabet or other character?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/14/123129), as this approach can be found under point 3 in the [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/21/123129).

Comment: @UlrikeFischer thanks.  It didn't in Latex workshop but it turned out that it did in plaintext.  This helped me identify the way to get it to work: add latex to the list of Unicode-latex extensions.  Intriguing that's not turned on by default given the name of the package.  Without it, one has to use an additional key combination.

Comment: @dexteritas no.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way is to use snippets.

Press Command + Shift + P and enter `snippets`

[image]

Choose latex

[image]

```
"calligraphic K": {
    "prefix": "\\scrK",
    "body": "",
    "description": "insert unicode character U1D4A6"
},
```

Afterward, the file should look like this

[image]

I am on mac, but that shouldn't matter.

Comment: Thanks!  I'll accept that.

Answer (score 1):

If `latex` is not listed under the `Unicode-latex:Extensions` then the unicode command functionality that the `unicode-latex` extension offers does not work in the `LaTeX Workshop` extension without extra keystrokes.  So all I had to do was to add the line `latex` under the extensions.

With thanks to @UlrikeFischer and @dexteritas for their comments.

[image]